# Making a class template that is dependent on another template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-specialization, derived-class

So I have a set of classes that are all derived from a base class `RigidBody` (NOTE: In the following code `Tp` is used to specify a precision type (e.g. `float`), while `Tc` is ued to a specify a color type (e.g. `RGB`):

```
template <typename Tp>
class RigidBody {
    ...
}
```

These classes are `Model`, `Assembly`, `Light`, etc.  Below is an example of `Model`

```
template <typename Tp, typename Tc>
class Model : public RigidBody<Tp> {
    ...
}
```

I now need to write a templated `Instance` class that acts as a wrapper around all of these classes, and is also derived from `RigidBody`.  What I currently have is this:

```
template <typename Tp, typename ObjectType>
class Instance : public RigidBody<Tp> {
    ...
};
```

While this works, it feels clunky to need to specialize using (for example)

```
Instance<float, Model<float,RGB>>
```

Because the `float` is redundant.  I'd much rather just be able to use `Instance<Model<float,RGB>>`

I've read about "template template" syntax but that doesn't seem to address my issue.  I've tried:

```
template <template<typename Tp,typename Tc> typename ObjectType>
class Instance : public RigidBody<Tp> {
    ...
}
```

But this does not work because `Tp` is an undeclared identifier for the actual body of the class declaration.

Is there a way of getting the behavior how I would like?  Under no circumstance would I ever want to allow the instance to have a different precision from whatever object it is wrapping.

Comment: Just `template <typename T> class Instance`? And add a member typedef for `Tp` to `RigidBody` (assuming you made a typoe and it's a public base), so you can extract `Tp` from `T`.

Comment: You're correct that was a typo (I fixed it).  However I'm not entirely following what you mean.  How is `Tp` extracted from `T`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `class Instance` accept just `<typename ObjectType>`.

Add `using foo = Tp;` to `class RigidBody` (it must be public or protected).

Then you can use `typename ObjectType::foo` in `Instance` to access that type:

```
template <typename Tp>
class RigidBody
{
  public:
    using foo = Tp;
};

template <typename Tp>
class A : public RigidBody<Tp> {};

template <typename ObjectType>
class Instance : public RigidBody<typename ObjectType::foo> {};
```

Comment: Thank you once again.  Very illuminating example as always!